# Fine tuning weights in DBN

Tags: theano, deep-learning, dbn

In a Deep Belief Network, I have pretrained the net using CD-1. I have the weights and biases stored. Now can I run a supervised mlp code with dropout and initialise the weights as those obtained from pre training. Will it be equivalent to a DBN implemented with dropout fine tuning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> dropout fine tuning on DBN

means

> run a supervised mlp code with dropout and initialise the weights as those obtained from pre training

So yes, they are equivalent.